# python how to access class variables inside init

Tags: python

I want to access class variables inside the init

```
class Hare:
    APP = 10;

    def __init__(self):
        print(APP)

h = Hare()
```

its giving error

```
!!! NameError: name 'APP' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `self.APP = 10` and `print(self.APP)`? Also, semicolons are _technically_ valid in Python, but you can leave it out.

Comment: `self.APP` or `Hare.APP`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want :

```
class Hare:
    APP = 10

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.APP) # 10

h = Hare()
```